# Can you select several sub items in an array with [ ]?

Tags: javascript

Say for example I have an array :

```
[ "car", "fish", "javascript", "Star Wars" ]
```

And I want to select the first three in this array, but not `"Star Wars"`.

Can I do that by using brackets somehow? Like in Rails I could this by :

```
array[0..2]
```

Is there something similar in javascript?

Comment: `[ "car", "fish", "javascript", "Star Wars" ].slice(0, 3)` [ref](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`slice()` and `splice()` are your friends:-D

Edit: For your example

```
var newAr = [ "car", "fish", "javascript", "Star Wars" ].slice(0, 3);
```

Comment: Note that `splice` modified the array.

Comment: @RobW true, but you can't assume from the question that this wasn't intended...

Comment: Ah! Cool, super thank Christop. Silly StackOverflow makes me wait 2 minutes before giving you credit :D

Answer (score 1):

What you are asking for is called a `slice`.  In other languages, such as `perl`, you can use the bracket notation to select a slice, i.e. `[0..2]`.

However, in JavaScript, this notation is not natively supported.  Instead, you need to use the `.slice(0,3)` method.

It is important to note that the second parameter, the ending index, is the element *after* the last one you want in the sub-array.  Also, `slice()` does not modify the original array.  Instead, it returns a new array object.  If you want to modify the original array, use `splice()`.

Answer (score 0):

Here goes the example in action:

http://jsfiddle.net/latoyale/2MKKM/1/